# What are the ratios of vegetarians across genders?

Tags: veganism, vegetarian-diet, scientific-studies, statistics

What is the percent composition of vegetarians and vegans across the genders worldwide?

Which gender has the most number of vegetarians? Which gender has the most number of vegans?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to a YouGov biannual tracker from 2019-2024 that asks respondents to select either vegan, vegetarian, flexitarian, pescetarian, or meat eater:

- approximately 2-4% of women report being vegan and 5-8% as vegetarian. (2% vegan, 6% vegetarian in 2024)
- approximately 1-2% of men report being vegan and 3-6% as vegetarian. (3% vegan, 4% vegetarian in 2024)

This seems to show a trend of women being represented slightly more in the UK.

Source Link: https://yougov.co.uk/topics/society/trackers/dietery-choices-of-brits-eg-vegeterian-flexitarian-meat-eater-etc

According to a Gallup poll of US Americans, women (6%) are more likely than men (2%) to say they eat a vegetarian diet. But for veganism, because only 1% of US Americans report being vegan, there weren't any differences found between men and women.

Source Link: https://news.gallup.com/poll/510038/identify-vegetarian-vegan.aspx

I was unable to find any studies that included or reported on additional genders.